# switches in Triangle program

Tags: c, linux

A weeks ago, I started learning about the Triangle program, which is used to generate meshes.
I attach the link from where you can download its zip file and read about it:
[http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake/triangle.html)

I am having trouble running the example using in Linux Ubuntu, which is supposed to be run trivially.

In particular, I don't understand what are exactly the switches that are mentioned in the makefile.

How exactly am I supposed to choose the optimization using switches? Do I need to modify the C source code or is something I need to specify before compiling it on Linux terminal somehow?
Besides, I am required to use the -DLINUX switches in order for arithmetics to run well. I would also need to know where I need to specify this.

If it helps, I am getting errors in the terminal notifying me that there are: "Undefined reference to sqrt" and " "Undefined reference to cos".

I really need help on this because my understanding on Linux and C is quite weak.

Thanks very much.

Comment: "Undefined reference to <math functions>" need to be compiled with the `-lm` switch, as in `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra ... -lm`

Comment: Sounds like you need an introduction to building C programs on the command-line, or you need to find an IDE that can set things up for you properly and let you focus on the code. This sort of thing is *highly* technical and not something we can just explain in five minutes here. You'll need to find a good reference and work from that.

Comment: Start small: Write a "hello world" program and get it to run, then work up to things like `Makefile` and using `ld`. Projects like this can be extremely idiosyncratic and may not make any sense at all, even to us, because of their quirky build system. Prior to things like CMake where there's *some* standardization, the build process was usually quite different from one project to another.

Comment: @tadman. In theory, all the code is already written and I am not supposed any of it. I just need to play with switches I guess but as I said, I am newbie at Linux and just know a little bit of C++.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with being "new", which is just called "learning". The only problem here is this is off-topic on Stack Overflow because it's too broad, you'll just have to work through building this knowledge up.